# Laravel em servidor Windows

Tags: windows, laravel-5.3

Pessoal fiz um site em Laravel 5.3 e quando fui publica-lo percebi que a hospedagem do cliente é em Windows 2008 na locaweb. Não tenho como alterar para Linux. Ja ativei o php 5.6. So não consigo fazer o site funcionar. Alguém pode me ajudar a configurar o web.config que tem lá e me orientar por gentileza. Obrigado

Comment: Cara, passei pelo mesmo problema e depois de pesquisar bastante encontrei a solução. Votei para fechar como duplicata porquê eu já fiz essa pergunta e lá tem a resposta. O link está acima.

Comment: Mas se ainda houver erros você pode recorrer a essa pergunta e editar com a dúvida específica.

Comment: Ok. Muito obrigado.